# What do these checksum images mean and whats their use?

Tags: image, hash

I notice starange Black and white images on many sites like on http://code.google.com/p/jquery-simpletip/downloads/detail?name=jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.pack.js&can=2&q=. Can anyone tell me their use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't checksums, they are [QR Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code), a 2-dimensional form of barcode (mouse over and it'll say 'File Download URL'). Devices such as mobile phones can scan the code off a PC monitor and visit that URL immediately, which is a lot simpler than having the user type the URL in.

QR Codes are more famously used by websites to link to Android market applications.

Answer (score 1):

They're called [QR Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code). They act just like a barcode but contains more data. Sometimes website encode their URL in them others encode Ads.

Hope that clears things =)